# 'Undefined variable' in Laravel 8 blade template on sending email

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my Laravel 8 project I try to send HTML e-mail, but get `Undefined variable` error.

I have this code in my controller:

```php
// here the $client has a model value
Mail::to($client)->send(new ClientCreated($client));
```

In my `app/Mail/ClientCreated.php` file:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use App\Client;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ClientCreated extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    private $client;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        // here the $this->client has a model value
        return $this->view('emails.client.created');
    }
}
```

Finally in my `resources/views/emails/client/created.blade.php` I have this code:

```php
<p>Dear{{ $client->name }}!</p>
```

And I got this error message:

```
Undefined variable: client (View: /home/vagrant/Code/myproject/laravel/resources/views/emails/client/created.blade.php)
```

I read the docs and search on the Stackoverflow, but not found any help.

Any idea what I made wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should make `$client` public not private:

```
 public $client;
```

> "There are two ways you may make data available to your view. First, any **public** property defined on your mailable class will automatically be made available to the view"

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Mail - Writing Mailables - View Data - Via Public Properties](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#view-data)

The other method would be calling `with`:

```
$this->view(...)->with('client', $this->client);
```

> "If you would like to customize the format of your email's data before it is sent to the template, you may manually pass your data to the view via the `with` method."

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Mail - Writing Mailables - View Data - Via the `with` Method](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#view-data)

If you do not want to change `$client` to `public` then use the second method.

Answer (score 10):

If you passed the variable to the view properly, but it still does not work, try to restart the queue in the console:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Comment: After wasting so much time on the problem, this finally solved it for me!! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad I didn't spend forever debugging. Thank you. Would have never tried this.

Comment: Thanks. This reminding release me from debugging after spent one hour already.

Answer (score 1):

You should make $client public

```
public $client;
```

Once the data has been set to a public property, it will automatically be available in your view, so you may access it like you would access any other data in your Blade templates.
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#view-data